# Change database from one format to another. What is most efficient way to do this?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I need to convert database in form

```
(3- column form) 

Col1   Col2   Col3
 45     23     A
 18     17     A
 16     14     B
 ................
 27     33     B
 13     19     C

to 

(4-column form)

Col1   A      B     C
 45    23 
 18    17
 16          14
  ..................
 27          33
 13                 19
```

I thought originally of iterating through original database (in Pandas form), accessing each string in `Col3`, and then based on if its `A`, `B` etc.,  dynamically create a SQL Insert INTO statement that enters into new table the required values only.

However, my dataset (database) is huge. So is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would create the new table structure,
insert into the new table structure using a pivot query on the existing table (to get the data in the format you need)
drop the original table then rename the new table.

Using the pivot query as the insert allows you to insert all rows at the same time.